# Open the process is the process ID is known

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, process

How will I open a link from my application using the process ID of the IE process.

I have two instances of IE open and I have process ID of one of them.

EDIT: Code I have written is below :

```
bool isActive = false;

        if (File.Exists("ProcessID.txt"))
        {
            processID = Convert.ToInt32(File.ReadAllText("ProcessID.txt"));
            Process[] activeProcess = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process proc in activeProcess)
            {
                if (proc.Id == processID)
                {
                    isActive = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //existingProcess = Process.GetProcessById(processID);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            if (isActive)
            {
                //Process oldProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                Process oldProc = Process.GetProcessById(processID);
                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(textBox1.Text);


                //string processName = oldProc.ProcessName;
                //string mainWindowTitle = oldProc.MainWindowTitle;                    
                //SetFocus(new HandleRef(null, oldProc.Handle));

                //psi.UseShellExecute = false;

                oldProc.StartInfo = psi;
                oldProc.Start();

                int prhandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
                label1.Text = prhandle.ToString();

                //File.WriteAllText("ProcessID.txt", prhandle.ToString()); 
            }
            else 
            {
                ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", textBox1.Text);
                newprocess.StartInfo = pi;
                newprocess.Start();

                int prhandle = newprocess.Id;
                label1.Text = prhandle.ToString();

                File.WriteAllText("ProcessID.txt", prhandle.ToString());                    
            }
        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Enter a url ");
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AgentFire Anything yet or are you still searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you can try something like this. There is some unnecessary casting going on and it's not that well written, but you should get the gist of it.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);

public void Navigate2URL(int processId, string strUrl)
{
    SHDocVw.ShellWindows SWs = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
    SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < SWs.Count; i++)
    {
        IE = (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)SWs.Item(i);

        uint pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr)IE.HWND, out pid);
        if ((IntPtr)IE.HWND == (IntPtr)pid)
        {
            object o = null;
            IE.Navigate2(strUrl, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this

```
Navigate2URL(12108, "mydomain.com");
```

Note that this will change the URL for all the tabs inside this PID, if you want to only target a specific tab in the IE process, then the code is longer and more hackish.

Comment: Well certainly I want to open a new tab. and do not want to affect other tabs. Is is possible to somehow set focus to that IE process and then pass the URL to that instance?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var iExplorerInstances = new ShellWindows();
    if (iExplorerInstances.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var instance in iExplorerInstances)
        {
            var iExplorer = (InternetExplorer)instance;
            uint processId = 0;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr)iExplorer.HWND, out processId);
            if (processId == 1212) // your ID
            {
                iExplorer.Navigate("http://google.de", 0x800); //0x800 means new tab
            }  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //No iexplore running, use your processinfo method
    }
}
```

You have to add a reference to C:\Windows\System32\SHDocVw.dll

Comment: iExplorer.Navigate("http://google.de", 0x800); throwing error that number of arguments are not correct.